# Fancybox in Wordpress site doesn't show PDF

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-2

PDF won't show in Fancybox on [this website](http://www.thebistronomy.com) (scroll to Menu & Reservations to trigger fancybox).

Load Fancybox

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?ver=4.0.1'></script>
```

HTML

```
<a class="hiddenlink fancybox" rel="group1" href="wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ontdekkingsmenu.pdf"></a>
<a class="hiddenlink fancybox" rel="group1" href="wp-content/uploads/2015/02/bistronomy_uitnodiging.jpg"></a>
```

JS + Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        type: 'html',
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade'
    });
});
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var docHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var bodyClass = $('body').attr('class');
    if(scrollTop >= docHeight) {
        if(bodyClass == 'visited') {
            //nothing
        } else {
            $('body').addClass('visited');
            $('.hiddenlink').fancybox().trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

At first I hadn't declared the `type: 'html'`, but I found this solution together with `type: 'iframe'` in similar posts, but these solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Every content needs its own `type` : PDF documents should work fine with `type:"iframe"` but images need `type:"image"`.

What you can do is to remove the `type: "html"` from your script

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    // type: 'html', // don't need this
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade'
});
```

... and add the special fancybox `data-fancybox-type` attribute to your HTML code to indicate the `type` of content fancybox should handle like :

```
<a class="hiddenlink fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" rel="group1" href="document.pdf">Opens PDF</a>

<a class="hiddenlink fancybox" data-fancybox-type="image" rel="group1" href="image.jpg">Opens image</a>
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**